# How did the Kohanim eat in the Azara?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, korban

As far as I know, it was forbidden to sit in the Azara unless you were a king descended from David.

So it seems the Kohanim must have been forced to stand while eating their portions of the Kodshei Kodashim. But this seems to me like a very undignified way of eating food, and an affront to the holiness of the Korbanot.

So what did they do?

Comment: If you view eating as Avoda and not a Temple-perk, then standing is dignified. This wasn't a lunch break. This was a way of serving God.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Tosafot to Yoma 25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Yoma.25a.6.1?lang=bi) discuss whether the *kohanim* sat down to eat *korbanot* in the *'azarah*. They suggest three approaches:

1. **They would eat standing up in the *'azarah*, due to the prohibition on sitting there.** Only *kodashim kalim* (eaten throughout the city) could be eaten sitting down.
2. **The prohibition on sitting in the *'azarah* does not apply to things which are part of the temple service,** which includes eating *korbanot*. Thus, they would sit in the *'azarah* to eat *korbanot*.
3. **The word למשחה** ('as a perquisite', [Bamidbar 18:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.18.8?lang=bi)) **used in reference to eating *korbanot* teaches that they must be eaten while sitting,** notwithstanding the general prohibition on sitting in the *'azarah*. Thus, they would sit in the *'azarah* to eat *korbanot*.

Comment: See also Tosfos Zevachim 16a and Shitta Mekubetzes (ad loc.)